# How to schedule a periodic task but stop and return result if a condition is fulfilled (Java)

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice, periodic-task

1. I need to execute a certain task periodically within a certain timeout.
2. But dependent on the result of the task, I want to stop before the end of the timeout is reached. And in addition I need a reference to the currently executed task in order to have the chance to ask for the result.

Solution to 1) is no problem, because it can be solved with the little code snipped shown below. But I can not figure out how to integrate 2). So with this code example, I would like that the beeper object runs code which can have a positive or a negative result and based on (for example) a positive result, the beeper task should no longer be executed periodically.

```
class BeeperControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beepForAnHour() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
        };
     
    final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = 
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
    
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
    }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `run` method if condition is fulfilled then invoke `scheduler.shutdown()`. That should do exactly what you want.

```
public void beepForAnHour() {
    final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
          System.out.println("beep"); 
          if(isMyCondition() {
           scheduler.shutdown();
          }
        }
    };
```

See javadoc for [ExecutorService.shutdown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--)

Comment: Did not work for me, the scheduler kept running. And the problem with something like this is that i do not get a reference to the current result of the currently executed task. i adjusted the question accordingly

Comment: If you need a reference to the result of executed task look into the Future. Here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html